# Calculating the matter-energy density of the Universe

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime

Reading about the value $\Omega$ which is the ratio between the mass-energy density of the universe and the required mass - energy density of the universe to ensure linear expansion. I understand that if the value of $\Omega$ < 1 then space-time will warp into a saddle shape and vice-versa.

My question is, how is the mass-energy density of the universe measured / predicted / calculated if we are restricted to the observable universe and its CMB?

Comment: where did you read it ?

Comment: "Astrophysics for people in a hurry" - Neil deGrasse Tyson Simple and fun read! @magma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CMB has a lot of information in it, that's the reason missions such as [COBE](https://science.nasa.gov/missions/cobe), [WMAP](https://map.gsfc.nasa.gov/) or [Planck](https://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Planck) are so important. Simply put the CMB is the result of the interaction among the various components in the universe before decoupling. This implies that a slight different universe to ours would generate a whole different power of fluctuations.

The image below shows the behavior of the various peaks in the CMB for different cosmological models

[image]

The idea is then select the best cosmological model based on the best observations available for the fit.

Comment: How many adjustable parameters does such models usually have? Or, to be specific, how many does the current best one have?

Comment: @andrehgomes Around 10, you can look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model#Parameters) page for more details